# How to store the image in android device

Tags: android, image, storage

I have the set of images from server.I need to store the image in device.How to do that.Can anyone guide me to store the images in android device.What is the best way to do this process.

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: After downloading the images it would be a good idea to keep them all in a folder you created with your app name `App/images`, then you can get the path to your images and do what ever else you need to do for your app

Comment: If the image sizes are larger,whether it will be problem for storage?

Comment: Sizes are always a concern when storing images, but you could compress the image quality and save a bit of space but you will still have to download the images. You could try one of those answers to figure out how to download the images, alternatively you could `LazyLoad` the images but this depends on your implementation of the pictures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download image from url and store it in sd card. Whenever you want to display images then simply load that image. Here simple code for this work.

```
   private void downloadImagesToSdCard(String downloadUrl,String imageName)
  {
try{
    URL url = new URL(downloadUrl); //you can write here any link

    File myDir =  new File("/sdcard"+"/"+Constants.imageFolder);
    //Something like ("/sdcard/file.mp3")


    if(!myDir.exists()){
        myDir.mkdir();
        Log.v("", "inside mkdir");

    }

    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = imageName;
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 

         /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
       HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)ucon;
      httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
      httpConn.connect();

      if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
      }

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
       // InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        int size = 1024*1024;
        byte[] buf = new byte[size];
        int byteRead;
        while (((byteRead = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1)) {
            fos.write(buf, 0, byteRead);
            bytesDownloaded += byteRead;
        }
        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */

        fos.close();

}catch(IOException io)
{
    networkException = true;
    continueRestore = false;
}
catch(Exception e)
{   
    continueRestore = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Hope this will help you.